# Webview doesn't work well after use javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm building an app that uses a webview. It loads mobile version of a website. But my client wanted me to change and delete some text. 
I did it with javascript but after i did this, some sliders stopped working anymore. Without javascript it works perfect. But i have to change and remove texts somehow.

my webview settings;

```
wSettings=webView.getSettings();
        wSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.evdusum.com");
```

and the javascript that i used in onPageFinished;

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                String link1 = "SİTEDE ARAYIN";
                String link2 = "ARA";
                String a="Bu sitede kullanılan yazılı ya da görsel dokümanlar izinsiz kullanılamaz.";
                String b=" ";
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('" + link1+"', '" + link2+"')})()");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('" + a+"', '" + b+"')})()");

                ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.start)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
```

Comment: dnt use 2 times view.loadUrl is not indicated.The best is to write your javascript code into your page , and call your javascript from webview

Comment: @DionisL i can't understand what you mean. I can't edit this webpage and i cant write codes into this page.

Comment: You can search on google how to view page source in webview , get the page source make modifications and load it again into webview .Is better

Answer (score 0):

Until Android api 18 (JELLY_BEAN_MR1) you can use this `view.loadUrl("javascript:");`. Just use ONE call to insert and call your js. If you need to perfome long code, build a function and call it at the "same call" of `webView.loadUrl()`.

Some example:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
    "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
    "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
    "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
    "script.innerHTML =  function your_function(var1, var2){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(var1, var2); return true;}" +
    "parent.appendChild(script);" +
    "your_function('"+link1+"','"+link2+"')" + ";})();");
```

Android api >=19 use `webView.evaluateJavascript`. Here some example:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() {" +
        "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
        "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
        "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
        "script.innerHTML =  function your_function(var1, var2){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(var1, var2); return true;}" +
        "parent.appendChild(script);" +
        "return your_function('"+link1+"','"+link2+"');})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        Log.v("TAG", "Response from JS"+value)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You but  I checked Build Version and used only one loadUrl(""); and this didn't work for me.

Comment: Have tried your own example at a normal browser? I mean, put this into a html page and run? Is it work properly?